# how to get Text inside the Div and button tag

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<div class="content-wrapper" style="min-height: 611px;">
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    The new customer role has been added successfully.
</div>
```

How to get this Text after the Button tag. I tried many ways, but I am not able to get it.

```
//div[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable']
```

Comment: can you share your site url

Comment: Please clarify your question and include what you've tried.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `//div[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable']/text()` xpath to locate the text `The new customer role has been added successfully.` But selenium doesn't support `text()` method in xpath to locate a text node.

> Try below code to get the text from `<button>` tag.

```
String button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='close'][@type='button']")).getText();       
System.out.println(button);
```

> Try below code to get the text `The new customer role has been added successfully.`

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
Object str = js.executeScript("var value = document.evaluate(\"//button[@class='close']/following::node()[contains(., 'The new customer role has been added successfully.')]\",document, null, XPathResult.STRING_TYPE, null); return value.stringValue;");      
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

You can explore in detail [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate)

Refer below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: It returns 'x' but he wants text after button

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Have you try second xpath? Try once and then update me.

Comment: OK I will try and let u know

Comment: Nope @janish it also print X

Comment: Wait I will attach Image and see for me it is clearly display the proper result..refer above attached image for more detail.

Comment: @iamsankalp89 Have you Re-verified this issue?

Comment: @Raghavendra K, Have you try this code? Is it working fine for you?

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted`, if it's resolved your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your HTML but you can try with this XPath

```
//*[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable']
```

Using java `getText()` will get your text from html

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable']")).getText();
```

let me know XPath is work or not

Comment: This seems not the correct answer. Because when you execute above answer as `String a = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable']")).getText();
  System.out.println(a);` It will give you both text, `Button tag text` and `after the button tag text.` but @Raghavendra K wants text after the button tag only.

Answer (score 0):

I think you already tried with below xpath

```
//*[@class='alert alert-success alert-dismissable']
```

Could you please check whether the alert box (I assume it's an alert box from the html given) pops up as new window . In that case you need to switch to new window.

Also check whether there is an overlay attribute for the alert pop-up